# How do I split this column with multiple types of data into [['education' , 'Ph.D., MIT'] ... into multiple columns?

Tags: r

I have a column with with multiple types of data inside of different types. It is JSON-esque but I don't quite know how to make this work with `jsonlite` or `tidyr::separate`. How can I split this into multiple columns?

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~ID, ~data,
        "A", "[['education', 'Ph.D., MIT'], ['interests', 'Econometrics, Causal Inference']]",
        "B", "[['function', 'Social']]",
        "C", "[['research_interests', 'S&P']]",
        "D", "[['field', 'American Politics']]")
```

My expected outcome would be something like:
[image]

Comment: So what exactly do you want the output to look like? Im not sure what the resulting columns should look like.

Comment: so the first values in the square brackets would be the column name and others would be in the values. i.e., column names in order would be `education`, `interests`, `function`, `research_interests` ... Does this make sense?

Comment: sure, i just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is probably a more elegant way to do this, but see if this produces your desired results:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(~ID, ~data,
        "A", "[['education', 'Ph.D., MIT'], ['interests', 'Econometrics, Causal Inference']]",
        "B", "[['function', 'Social']]",
        "C", "[['research_interests', 'S&P']]",
        "D", "[['field', 'American Politics']]")

column_names <- str_extract_all(data$data, "\\['(?<=').*?(?=')")
column_names <- map(column_names, ~ str_remove(.x, "\\['"))
names(column_names) <- data$ID

values <- str_extract_all(data$data, ",[:space:]'(?<=').*?(?=')")
values <- map(values, ~ str_remove(.x, ",[:space:]'")) 
names(values) <- data$ID

val_df <- data.frame(values)%>%
            gather("ID", "val")
col_df <- data.frame(column_names)%>%
            gather("ID", "col")

bind_cols(col_df, val_df) %>%
  distinct()%>%
  spread(col, val, fill = NA)%>%
  select(-ID1)
```

Unfortunately, this approach depends on at least 2 assumptions:

1. Column names are always found in the following format "['column_name'"
2. Values are always found in the following format ", 'value']"

I'm not sure if will scale to the rest of your data, but let me know if this works.

## Edit To Address Additional Criteria in Comments

If one ID has two records for one column, you have at least two options:

1. Create a second record for the ID
2. `paste` the two values into a single value

Here is the additional example record from the comments (with my edits from 'research interest' to 'research interest**s**', assuming they should be the same as the original data):

```
"E", "[['research_interests', 'American Politics'], ['research_interests', 'Democratization']]"
```

#### Option 1: Create a second record

This should give you two records for 'E'

```
# Replace last step of the original answer with this:
two_records <- bind_cols(col_df, val_df) %>%
                distinct()%>%
                group_by(col)%>%
                mutate(grouped_id = row_number()) %>%
                spread(col, val, fill = NA)%>%
                select(-ID1, -grouped_id)
```

#### Option 2: Paste two values into 1

This looks more like your original desired output

```
# Replace last step of original answer with this:
paste_records <- bind_cols(col_df, val_df) %>%
                  distinct()%>%
                  group_by(col)%>%
                  mutate(grouped_id = row_number()) %>%
                  spread(col, val, fill = NA)%>%
                  select(-ID1, -grouped_id)

paste_records <- paste_records %>%
  split(paste_records$ID)%>%
  map_df(mutate_if, function(x)length(unique(x))>1, .funs = list(function(x)paste(x,collapse = ", ")))%>%
  distinct()
```

Comment: I think this almost worked! The two assumptions hold, but I found that some rows in the have the same "column" twice which I think is causing in the issue -- i.e., `"E", "[['research_interest', 'American Politics'], ['research_interest', 'Democratization']]"`. Do you have any advice?

Comment: You would need to decide how you want your output to look. `spread()` doesn't like it when you try to jam two values into the same cell. You can create two records for E or you can `paste` both values into one cell. I'll update the answer with both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to MillionC - this is sort of a brute force method and makes a fair amount of assumptions about the data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~ID, ~data,
        "A", "[['education', 'Ph.D., MIT'], ['interests', 'Econometrics, Causal Inference']]",
        "B", "[['function', 'Social']]",
        "C", "[['research_interests', 'S&P']]",
        "D", "[['field', 'American Politics']]") -> df

df %>% 
  separate(data, into = c("x1", "x2"), sep = "\\], \\[") %>% 
  gather(x, data, -ID, na.rm = T) %>% 
  separate(data, into = c("k", "v"), sep = "', '") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(k:v), ~gsub("\\[|]|'", "", .)) %>% 
  select(-x) %>% 
  spread(k, v)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   ID    education  field      `function` interests         research_intere…
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>             <chr>           
#> 1 A     Ph.D., MIT <NA>       <NA>       Econometrics, Ca… <NA>            
#> 2 B     <NA>       <NA>       Social     <NA>              <NA>            
#> 3 C     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>              S&P             
#> 4 D     <NA>       American … <NA>       <NA>              <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Even in this example this is dropping part of the data, for example in the 'Ph.D., MIT', MIT is getting dropped

Comment: Good looks - I've edited my code to account for this. That said, I do feel there has to be a better way to do complete this task.